# Output_precision(); Octave

Tags: octave

Hi after calling this code (Octave) I get an answer with 7 digits of precision, I need only 6. It is worth mentioning that on different data-set the output is normal(with 6 digits);

```
output_precision(6);
Prev
```

output:

```
Prev =
   0.1855318
   0.2181108
   0.1796457
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is a little late but I wanted to add an answer for anyone with the same question in the future.

According to the [function reference](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/output_precision.html) for `output_precision()`, the argument passed to the function (in this case, 6) specifies the *minimum* number of significant figures, which only guarantees that future numeric output won't have *less than* that number of significant figures.

From what I've seen, if you use `output_precision(new_val)` before displaying an array (e.g., `Prev` in the question), then octave will round the element with the least digits before the decimal place to have `new_val` significant figures and then all other elements will be rounded to have the same number of digits after the decimal place as that initial rounded result. If you use a statement to output a single value instead of an array, then the output is just rounded to `new_val` significant figures. However, ***I don't know if this behavior is guaranteed*** .

Here's a short example of what I mean:

```
% array defined with values having 5 digits after decimal
F = [401.51670 313.70753 -88.55225 188.50067 280.21988 354.51821 54.51821 350];
output_precision(4)
F
output_precision(6)
F
```

Output:

```
F =
   401.52  313.71  -88.55  188.50  280.22  354.52  54.52  350.00

F =
   401.5167  313.7075  -88.5523  188.5007  280.2199  354.5182  54.5182  350.0000
```

It can be a little quirky if you try to round the values too much. When I used `output_precision(3)` and then output F, the numbers were actually rounded as if my system's default precision, 5, was still active. However, when I used elements with only 2 or 3 digits after the decimal to define another array, it displayed as expected with `output_precision(3)`.

[Check out *Octave Forge* if you ever need docs for octave features](https://octave.sourceforge.io/docs.php). It's not perfect but it's something. Hope this was helpful.